# Creating a graph of incidence of different events over time in r

Tags: ggplot2, events, curve

In R, I would like to create a graph over time, with the incidence of the occurrence of each event. I would like to have a curve for each type of event over time. I have about 1000 subjects, I give an example of the dataset I have.

| ID | week | event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 132 | 23 | A |
| 133 | 11 | B |
| 134 | 2 | C |
| 135 | 3 | A |
| 136 | 17 | C |

In the graph I would like in the X-axis the time to the event (week), in the Y-axis the incidence of subjects with the event.And I would like a different curve for each event.